# Android Studio Offline Map/Navigation

Tags: java, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'll be doing an app for my thesis. My thesis is a Offline Map which includes landmarks/routing. My thesis Maps is only for my City here in the philippines. I tried to use OSMDroid and failed to produce the wanted result.

What I want is (if possible) I want this to happen in my app:

1. Install APK
2. Prompt the user which country he/she wants to use
3. Download the chosen country for offline use.
4. Done

Here's my code in OSMDroid

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final GeoPoint myCity = new GeoPoint(14.54321,120.23451);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);

        IMapController mapViewController = mapView.getController();
        mapViewController.setZoom(13);
        mapViewController.setCenter(myCity);
    }
}
```

Here's what I've done:

1. I Use Mobac to a portion of the map
2. Save it to my Internal Phone Memory(i named it MapquestOSM)
3. Run the program

But when I run the program it's just Blank.
I Don't Mind using OSMDroid again as long as it will produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet you didn't do anything to tell osmdroid that you want a different map source. Here's a few pointers to help

- if you use mobac to create a zip file, it source names have to match. i.e. if you get Mapnik tiles, then use the Mapnik tile source in osmdroid. Mapquest tiles, mapquest source.
- zip files have an upper limit in android, use sqlite instead (also head the first point).
- tell the MapView you want offline maps (setUseDataconnection(false);)

If you still have issues (and are using zip files) try altering the contents of the zip to have the first directory = Mapnik. Then using the default tile source in osmdroid.

Until my PR gets merged (to switch tile providers at runtime) and a new release cut, that's really your only option.

Edit: osmdroid only looks in /sdcard/osmdroid/ for map tiles.

Comment: maybe thats my problem. i dont have sdcard. i i only have internal storage in my device. any other solution for that?

Comment: internal storage is actually /sdcard. try "adb shell" then "ls /sdcard/"

Comment: is there any way to lower the MB of zip file in MOBAC? because i need my whole country to have a offline map

Comment: Map data is big. Try a different tile source or sqlite

Comment: do you have any tutorial for that? been thingking if its possible to use MAPS.ME + My App. when viewing a particular place ill Intent MAPS.ME.

Comment: I would recommend against tile data and instead use vector data like mapsforge

Comment: hello. how to use it? thanks.. does it support offline map and will it lists restaurant/hotels something likethat.